# How to add 2 column values together and format output

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I want to add to column values together and then format the result in Oracle SQL. I thought I could do something like:

```
to_char(INVOICE_NET, '9,999,999.99') + to_char(INVOICE_TAX, '9,999,999.99')  AS GROSS_PRICE
```

This fails as I guess these are no longer numbers
Then I thought this may work:

```
INVOICE_NET + INVOICE_TAX AS to_char(GROSS_PRICE, '9,999,999.99')
```

This also fails. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why not use to_char(INVOICE_NET + INVOICE_TAX, '9,999,999.99') AS GROSS_PRICE ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `nvl()` functions to the **net** and **tax** columns based on the [comment advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270261/how-to-add-2-column-values-together-and-format-output#comment18087383_13270261) from [wxyz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1716357/wxyz).

So now it like this:

```
to_char(nvl(INVOICE_NET,0) + nvl(INVOICE_TAX,0), '9,999,999.99') AS GROSS_PRICE
```

and works.